# Как в python передать функции аргументы из строковой переменной

Tags: python, функции

Предположим, у нас есть функция, принимающая произвольное количество аргументов, в том числе и именованных:

```
def my_function(*args, **kwds):
    print(args)
    for key, value in kwds.items():
        print(f"{key}={value}")
```

Есть строковая переменная, содержащая аргументы, которые нужно передать в функцию:

```
parameters = "1, 2, 'abc', arg1 = 5, arg2 = 'string'"
```

Как передать функции аргументы из этой строки? Мне нужно, чтобы выполнилось вот так:

```
my_function(1, 2, 'abc', arg1 = 5, arg2 = 'string')
```

Парсить `parameters`? Есть ли способ проще?

Спасибо!

Comment: Парсить. По-другому никак.

Comment: есть eval(), но это большая дыра в безопасности, если вы не сами задаете эту строку

Answer (score 0):

Методом строки split() и парсить список.Проще,если поменять подход алгоритма в сторону enum.Делаю так,допустим из командной строки приходит "make_img".У меня

```
act1=0
act2=1
make_img = 2
comms=['act1','act2','make_img']
ind=comms.index('make_img')
...
op=ind
if op==make_img:
 # ops1
elif op==act1
 # ops2
```

Так строки могут стать литералами программы)

Comment: Идея понятна, но мне не подойдёт. Видимо, действительно только парсинг, благо он несложен в данном конкретном случае. Всё равно удивляет этот момент: передать именованные переменные в коде в функцию можно, словарём можно, а то же самое строкой - уже нет. И даже eval, чёрт бы с ней, с безопасностью, тут не поможет.

Comment: Строки они как бы вне программы существуют, а именованные параметры это литералы - природа языка.